# onScroll Gesture when using scroll view

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-gesture

I have a scroll view witch for some reason i don't want to scroll automatically!! I want to measure the scroll distance first, then do some calculation and then use scrollView.scrollBy() function to scroll. Also when i reach the end of scrollView i still want to capture scroll gesture. I can't use scrollView scroll listener because

- First Scroll Happens, then i will be notified, not the other way around
- Second If i reach the end of scroll i don't know how much scroll i missed. for example if i had content in my scroll view i would of scrolled 600px but since i'm near the end i only get 100px scroll. I need to know about extra 500px to do some animations).

I created a custom scroll view without scroll by making on touch event not calling the parent. Then i used a gesture detector to detect amount of scroll and i defined a listener to send back this distance to activity that uses the scroll view. and after that i'm using scrollview.scrollBy() to scroll that amount. It all works except screen lags and scrolling is not smooth at all! So what I'm missing here?

here is my code for custom scrollview

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

public interface ScrollGestureListener {
    void onScrollGesture(int dy);
}

private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
private ScrollGestureListener listener;


public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
}


private void init(){
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getContext(), this);
}

public void setScrollGestureListener(ScrollGestureListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean result = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
    //return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    SLog.d("l: " + l + " t: " + t);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
//        SLog.d("onDown: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                       float velocityX, float velocityY) {
//        SLog.d( "onFling: " + event1.toString() + event2.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
//        SLog.d( "onLongPress: " + event.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                        float distanceY) {
    SLog.d( "onScroll: " + distanceY + " -- " + e1.toString()+e2.toString());

    if(listener != null)
        listener.onScrollGesture((int) distanceY);

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
//        SLog.d( "onShowPress: " + event.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
//        SLog.d( "onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}
```

and here is my activity code that uses this scrollview

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomScrollView.ScrollGestureListener {
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
private CustomScrollView scrollView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    scrollView = (CustomScrollView) findViewById(R.id.test_scroll_view);
    scrollView.setScrollGestureListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onScrollGesture(int dy) {
    scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, dy);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**DON'T** modify the behavior of scroll view. There are alot of optimizations under the hood that make the scrolling smooth.
As a work around, you can overlay a transparent view on top of the scrollView. Eg. A view *sOverlay* is overlayed on top of the scrollView in the xml file. Override the on touch listener & return false. Apply your gesture listener & algorithm on sOverlay view. To know about the amount of travel the scrollView is going to perform, get top position *Y1* of the scrollView and bottom position *Y2* of the scrollView.

```
Y1 = scrollView.getScrollY();
Y2 = scrollView.getScrollY() + scrollView.getHeight();
```